# how to apply transform rotate all browse in inline css using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I use,

```
jQuery('.active').css(
           'transform',
           'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
           '-webkit-transform',
           'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
           '-moz-transform',
           'rotate('+angle+'deg)'
);
```

but not a work in other browser.

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: I dint get the point what you are asking

Comment: can you explain it in clear

Comment: Please post which browser you are using and in which browser it is not working? (with version in case of Internet explorer or safari)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create a class with name like `.active` and then use [.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method.

However take a look at the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kujisisi/1/edit)** first.

**Here is the jQuery Code**

```
$('.active').css({ 
  'transform': 'rotate(-20deg)', 
  '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(-20deg)', 
  '-moz-transform': 'rotate(-20deg)',
  'margin-top':'5em'
});
```

Comment: but all assign inline css

Answer (score 1):

It should be written as this

```
jQuery('.active').css({
   'transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
   '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)'
   '-moz-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
jQuery(".active").css({
 transform: 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
 MozTransform: 'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
 WebkitTransform: 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'
})
```

Correct syntax is,

```
.css({
    property : value,
    property1 : value,
    ...
});
```

**[Reference](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css3-transitions-and-jquery.shtml)**